# Why do I get a "SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target" from my java application?

Tags: java, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, squid

We have a java application (Java 17 temurin) which calls a third party vendor to obtain data through https. As a part of the call, we use [Squid proxy version 5.7](http://www.squid-cache.org/) to inspect any outgoing calls. This was something that was always working, but as of March 3rd, we started to get the following exception intermittently.

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:371)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:314)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:309)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1357)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1232)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1175)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:458)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:201)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1505)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1420)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:580)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:187)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:142)
    at com.github.scribejava.core.model.Response.<init>(Response.java:30)
    at com.github.scribejava.core.model.OAuthRequest.doSend(OAuthRequest.java:57)
    at com.github.scribejava.core.model.OAuthRequest.send(OAuthRequest.java:37)
    ... 117 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1341)
    ... 134 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
    ... 139 common frames omitted
```

We've checked the cert chain by using a forked version of [InstallCert](https://github.com/escline/InstallCert) when calling the outbound URL from the EC2 instance that our code resides in, and it says there are no errors. We were expecting to see some errors here, but we aren't even sure that squid proxy shows up when we debug the cert chain through InstallCert.

```
ec2-user@<IP>:~$ java DebugCert <external-url> --n=0
Loading KeyStore /usr/lib/jvm/temurin-17-jdk-amd64/lib/security/cacerts...
Opening connection to <external-url> ...
Starting SSL handshake...

No errors, certificate is already trusted

Server sent 3 certificate(s):
```

Does anyone know what this could be? Like I said before, the issue only happens intermittently.

**UPDATE**

We've been able to determine that squid is somehow mucking up the certificate chain as shown below. It does this seemingly at random. Does anyone have any idea as to why squid would do this?

```
 1 Subject CN=<destination>
   Issuer  CN=squid
   sha1    <numeric>
   md5     <numeric>

 2 Subject CN=squid
   Issuer  CN=squid
   sha1    <numeric>
   md5     <numeric>

 3 Subject CN=squid
   Issuer  CN=squid
   sha1    <numeric>
   md5     <numeric>
```

Comment: Have you checked all certificates in the chain regarding their expiration date? A problem like that would be logically if the problem appeared after a certain date.